# Unable to attach debugger with Visual Studio 2010 on WIndows 7 64 bit VM machine

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, 64-bit, debugging

I'm running on a VM with Windows 7 64 bit and an installation of Visual Studio 2010. The debugger won't attach manually either. I assume there is an issue with the 64 bit machine running VS as 32 and the installation of debugger. Anyone find a good resolution?

Comment: The virtual machine is 64-bit? And you've installed Visual Studio in the virtual machine? You can't attach Visual Studio on the host to an application running inside of a VM.

Comment: Right, the workstation is a VM running 64 bit with VS installed and I'm attmepting to debug to the local dev. So there's no way to work this?

Comment: The error 'Unable to attach to application WebServer...debugger is not properly installed' Debugger works in Visual Studio 2008 and below so it's just 2010.

Comment: So you're trying to use remote debugging? Have you set that up in VS 2010?

Comment: I am running remote debugging on the vm.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be a permissions problem? Have you tried running VS 2010 as Administrator?

Comment: Found the issue, the name of the remote debugging host was slightly different from the qualifier name.